# we are unable to connect to the content you've requested. we apologize for the inconvenienceというエラーが解消されません

Tags: javascript, html5

下記ソースのように、現在ビデオプレーヤーの実装をしており、HTML画面を表示するとビデオプレーヤーの画面内に
「we are unable to connect to the content you've requested. we apologize for the inconvenience」と表示され、動画の再生が行われません。

また、コンソールにはエラーは出力されていません。

調査したところ、[このサイトの内容](http://forums.iis.net/p/1193755/2037281.aspx?Smooth%20Streaming%20plugin%20for%20OSMF%20Announcement%20amp%20Feedback)の下記文章より、crossdomain.xmlを編集する必要があると考えました。

> Your web server needs to serve a valid crossdomain.xml (e.g. http://www.yourdemowebserver.com/crossdoamin.xml ) to make this work.
>
> Below you can find a sample crossdomain.xml which allow all domain requests.
>
> If this doesn't helps, can you please send a fiddler output?
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <cross-domain-policy>
> <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
> </cross-domain-policy>
> ```

しかし、crossdomain.xmlがどこに置いてあるのか分かりません。

分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

また、crossdomain.xmlの設定方法についても上記参考サイトを参考にしようと思うのですが、
宜しければ設定方法についてご教授頂けると助かります。

```
<body>
// OFMF player
    <object width="200" height="50">
        <param name="movie" value="http:/省略/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf"></param>
        <param name="flashvars" value="src=http:省略/Manifest&autoPlay=true&plugin_AdaptiveStreamingPlugin=http:/省略/MSAdaptiveStreamingPlugin-v1.0.3-osmf2.0.swf&AdaptiveStreamingPlugin_retryLive=true&AdaptiveStreamingPlugin_retryInterval=10"></param>
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false"></param>
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
        <param name="enableStageVideo" value="false"></param>
        <param name="wmode" value="direct"></param>
        <embed src="http:/省略/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf"
               type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
               allowscriptaccess="always"
               allowfullscreen="false"
               wmode="direct"
               flashvars="src=http:省略Manifest&autoPlay=true&plugin_AdaptiveStreamingPlugin=http:/省略/MSAdaptiveStreamingPlugin-v1.0.3-osmf2.0.swf&AdaptiveStreamingPlugin_retryLive=true&AdaptiveStreamingPlugin_retryInterval=10">
        </embed>
    </object>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問文では movie パラメータの URL が省略されていますが、 `http://osmf.org/dev/2.0gm/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf` でしょうか。`osmf.org` に置かれたswfファイルから、あなたのサーバーに置かれた動画等を読み込むことになりますが、この時「どのドメインからのリクエストに応じるか」という指定を行う必要があります。これが `crossdomain.xml` です。

このファイルは自分で作成する必要がありますから、まだあなたのサーバーには置かれていないはずです。質問文で引用されてるXMLを、`http://あなたのサーバー/crossdomain.xml` でアクセスできるように配置すれば解決するのではないでしょうか。

[カスタムポリシーファイル crossdomain.xml について - yoshiweb.NET](http://yoshiweb.net/blog/?itemid=162)